# using Matlab to reshape a 4d matrix into a cell array of vectors

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 4D matrix (dims - x,y,z,t). I want to reshape it to a 1D cell array of length `x*y*z` where each element is a long vector of size `t` which captures all elements at each volume location `(x,y,z)`.  After that I need to reshape it back.

I thought of looping over the array to do it since I can't really find a built in function to do it.

Any insights will be super helpful!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if this is that you want:

```
x = randn(2,3,4,5); % example data
x = reshape(x, [], size(x,4)); % collapse first three dimensions
x = mat2cell(x, ones(1,size(x,1)), size(x,2)); % split first dimension into cells
```

Answer (score 3):

Luis's answer is great for being semi-vectorized (`mat2cell` uses a loop).  If what you desire is a cell array of size `x*y*z` where each element is `t` long, it's possible to use a loop over each volume location and extract the `t` elements that "temporally" occupy this spot in 4D.  Make sure you [`squeeze`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) out any singleton dimensions to get the resulting vector.  This is something to consider if you wanted to go with the loop approach.  Assuming your matrix is called `A`, try the following:

```
B = cell(size(A,1)*size(A,2)*size(A,3), 1);
count = 1;
for ii = 1 : size(A,1) 
    for jj = 1 : size(A,2)
        for kk = 1 : size(A,3)
            B{count} = squeeze(A(ii,jj,kk,:));
            count = count + 1;
        end
    end
end
```

To get this back into a 4D matrix form, you'd just apply the same logic but in reverse:

```
Ar = zeros(size(A));
count = 1;
for ii = 1 : size(A,1) 
    for jj = 1 : size(A,2)
        for kk = 1 : size(A,3)
            Ar(ii,jj,kk,:) = B{count};
            count = count + 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Mentalist, eh? :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo I would say so :) The edit I made to the question is how I interpreted the question... "long vector" and "cell" don't jive together obviously.

Comment: @LuisMendo You're right. I interpreted it wrong. I need to edit.

Answer (score 3):

Like Luis' solution, but simpler and more complete:

```
% Transform to cell
x = randn(2,3,4,5); % example data
y = reshape(x, [], size(x,4));
z = num2cell(y,2);

% transform back 
x = reshape(cat(1,z{:}), size(x));
```

Comment: Very nice. You can simplify the reshaping back to 4D by just making the second argument to `reshape` be `size(x)`.  Beats typing out all those numbers!

Comment: Well done! I  keep forgetting about the two-input version of `num2cell`